# Why is Firefox so slow and heavy?

Tags: firefox, freeze, lag

For some reason, when I go to links the pages seem slow and heavy. It also has a lot of lag spikes between page loads. Basically it seems to freeze then load it all at once fast.

I'm currently using Firefox 25.

But when I use the same Chrome version, it seems to be very fast and smooth page loading.

The CPU it takes on average is about 400,000k.

**Extensions:**

- iMacros
- Leethax
- Ad Block Plus 2.4
- Ad Block Plus Pop-up Addon 0.9.1

**Computer stats:**

- 6 GB RAM
- Windows 7 Acer Aspire Laptop
- 500 GB HDD
- Intel Core i3-2370M

How do I make Firefox load like Google Chrome, without much freezing?

Comment: Also, there is no i4 processor

Comment: @CanadianLuke i3 my bad.

Comment: Try disabling all your extensions and try it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try starting Firefox in Safe Mode.  [This explains](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode).

If it works fine in Safe Mode, your extensions are at fault.

After some cursory searching and learing that Leethax is a game cheating tool, I'd surmise you are playing a lot of Flash games in your browser.

if you have 10 tabs of Flash-heavy games open, of course things will be slow.  Make sure your Flash plugin is updated to the latest version.  Since Chrome integrates Flash it may have an inherent speed advantage here.

If the extension itself is causing the slowness, there isn't much you can do if you aren't the developer.

Comment: All recent Firefox have plugins in another process - and it is usually faster than Chrome in recent versions.